# How to destroy / reload the canvas in html 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on an ebook application, I draw each page on canvas using PDF.js , the problem is , when I click on the button and turn to other page, I tried simply render on the same canvas again , but the canvas seems move to a wrong location or wrong size .

```
function renderPage(url) {
      canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      //clearCanvasGrid('canvas');

      PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdf) {
          // Using promise to fetch the page
          pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
            var viewport = page.getViewport(5); //scale 5

            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: ctx,
              viewport: viewport
            };

            page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
                initialZoomPage(viewport.height,viewport.width);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

So, are there any necessary step I need to do before redraw the page? Also , how can I destroy it if I would like to close the page? Thanks

Update:

```
function clearCanvasGrid(canvasID){
    canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID); //because we are looping //each location has its own canvas ID
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //context.beginPath();

    // Store the current transformation matrix
    context.save();

    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Restore the transform
    context.restore(); //CLEARS THE SPECIFIC CANVAS COMPLETELY FOR NEW DRAWING
}
```

I found a function to clear the canvas but it has .save , .setTransform and .restore besides clearRect, are they necessary? thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to clear out the canvas using [`context.clearRect(0,0, width, height)` (Reference)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clearrect.asp).

Alternatively, you can append a new canvas element (and possibly remove the old one, depending on whether you will want to display it again) each time you want a new page.  Something like this should do it:

```
var oldcanv = document.getElementById('canvas');
document.removeChild(oldcanv)

var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
canv.id = 'canvas';
document.body.appendChild(canv);
```

Just note that if you plan to keep more than one, each one must have a unique `id` instead of just `id="canvas"` (perhaps based on the page number - something like `canvas-1`).

---

**Answer to updated question**:

The `save`, `setTransform`, and `restore` are only necessary if you are doing (or somehow allowing users to do) transformation.  I don't know if the PDF.js library does any transformation behind the scenes, so it may be best to leave it there.

Comment: if I remove the canvas using "$('#canvas').remove()" and append it with $('body').prepend('<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>');, are there any problem of it? thanks

Comment: @user782104 Yes, that should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: If you remove the canvas, you shouldn't have to do `clearRect` because you are getting rid of the entire thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help , please have a look at the updated function

Comment: Thanks, it seems reuse and destory is just simply remove or append it

Answer (score 10):

try using [clearRect()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-clearrect), like:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning Aura components, a different approach is required:
The chart object, once created, is stored in an attribute.

```
 <aura:attribute name="chartObject" type="Object"/>
 <canvas id="chartId" aura:id="chartCanvas" </canvas>

let theChart = component.get("v.chartObject");
if (theChart != undefined) {
//alternative
//let chartStatus = Chart.getChart("chartId");
//if (chartStatus != undefined) {
   
   //update data if necessary
   //theChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = etc
   theChart.update();
}
else{
   var ctx = component.find("chartCanvas").getElement();
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: myData,
            options: {
                tension: 0.25,
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio :false,
                fill: true,
                
            }
        });
     component.set("v.chartObject", chart);
        
 }//endif chart exists
```